# Excel manipulating columns

Tags: excel, if-statement, calculated-columns

I want to build a formula in which it looks at a column in excel and if the column contains x as the value, it then finds the max of a different column.
For example. = IF(F:F = "rate", Max(k:k)) but this columns up as a value error. Could someone show me how to correctly write this formula.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to test if *rate* appears **even one time** or if **all cells contain** *rate* ???

Comment: Use [`Countif`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) to see if if the value is in column `F`

Comment: I want to find all instances of rate in column x, then find the max value of column y that contains rate in column x

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to SO - Next time, try to also show what you have tried yourself to solve the issue. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page should help.

```
{=MAX(IF(F:F="rate",K:K,""))}
```

enter as arry formula: ctrl+shift+enter

Comment: If this helped you, don't hesitate to upvote and accept the answer. Thanks